# What is the most efficient / best practise to Upsert 5000+ rows without Merge in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, merge, upsert

I have a web application which receives about 50 hits per second, and on each hit I am upsert'ing around 10 records in a central SQL Server database. Roughly once every 3 seconds I am upserting 5000+ rows for a single inbound connection.

Currently I have a stored procedure which takes XML as a parameter. I do an INSERT into my main table from my XML where a row field doesn't match, then update the whole table with values from my XML.

The operation isn't slow by any means, but I really would like to know the best way to do this. I am running on SQL Server 2005 so I don't have the MERGE operation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597357/what-is-the-preferred-merge-method-for-sql-server-2005

Comment: @Dalex: this isn't quite the same and is for one row, not for 5k rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do the UPDATE first otherwise you'll update the rows you've just inserted

```
SELECT .. INTO #temp FROM (shredXML)

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE ... FROM WHERE (matches using #temp)

INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM #temp WHERE NOT EXISTS

COMMIT
```

I'd also consider changing the XML to a temp table and use SQLBulkCopy. We've found this to be more efficient then parsing XML generally for more than a few hundred rows. If you can't change this then do you shred the XML into a temp table first?

Comment: I dont currently "tablulate" the XML. SqlBulkCopy would be an option from the C# into SQL, but 5000 rows is pretty much the limit of what we expect to run in a single operation.

Comment: With 5000 records I think you will feel the benefit of using SqlBulkCopy already. What times are you getting so far for your 5000 row upsert, and what would be too slow?

Comment: @richbayliss; shredding your XML once will be a "quick win" regardless of how much you implement A graphical query plan will show shredding XML (even once) into a temp table as the most expensive part of the stored proc call compared to the insert/update

Comment: @MyOtherMe - too slow would be over 30 seconds... since I need to respond to the client before a timeout. It is worth noting that I am expecting upto 1 million clients, each having up to 5000 records each = table with 5,000,000,000 rows... which I am concerned may be a bit too many :(

Comment: @richbayliss: With many concurrent 5k row inserts (for many clients) then every little help. You need to improve overall throughput and reducing XML shredding overhead (which is a double overhead if changed into XML in the client). 5 billion rows is less of a problem then many concurrent 5k inserts

Comment: @gbn so I should move to SqlBulkInsert to a temp table, then do the update followed by insert where not in from the temp table? What about  locks etc, is there anything I should be doing there?

Comment: @richbayliss: nah, we can worry about that later. FYI: I have of 40k rows+ per second at peak with mostly standard DELETE/INSERT pattern

Comment: @gbn OK, sounds good. I will migrate my code to SqlBulkInsert into a temp table, then do my update/insert from that. I already moved it to a shreded XML into temp -> update/insert, so shouldnt be a big change.

Comment: @gbn: Using the above technique - pre SqlBulkCopy - I am seeing 6 secs to update/insert 6500 rows. This is pretty good. I will report back with SqlBulkCopy and then close the question. You have been very helpful.

Comment: @richbayliss: Thanks. For completeness... is that one or two XML shreds? What about U/I vis I/U? No need to go to extremes but it'd be interesting to see I/U with 2xXML vs 1xXML with U/I

Comment: @gbn: See pastebin for details - single XML shred I belive with U/I http://pastebin.com/nX5GS9zM