# How can I insert a 100+k rows of XML into SQL Server 2012 in a fast way

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I have the following scenario/requirements for which I am not sure what is the best way to address to perform in the fastest way possible, looking for some guidance of features to use and examples of them, if available

I will receive anywhere between 10k to 100k of entities (in XML format) from a web service that I want to upsert (some rows might exist, others might not).

here are some of the requirements:

1. The source of the XML is a web service that I'm calling from C# code. Actually two different methods. For one of the methods, the return schema will be something flat that I can map directly to one of my tables. For the other, it will return an XML representation that I might need to work with in C# in order to be able to map it to flat entities for my tables. In that scenario, would it be best to do the modifications needed and then write to file to an XML to use as source?
2. The returned XML can contain up to 150k entities in XML, that may or may not exist in my tables yet, so I'm looking to upsert them. The files, when written to disk, can weight up to 20 megabytes. I asked if they could do JSON instead of XML, but apparently that's not a choice.
3. The SQL database is on a different server than my IIS server, so I rather avoid having the SQL server retrieve the XML from a file, I rather pass it from C# as a string or as a Table Value Parameter.
4. The tables are rather simple and don't have indexes other than the PK ones.

I've never been big on XML, although it got way easier with LINQ to XML, which I was initially using to parse each record and send individual inserts but the performance was just bad, so based on some research I've been doing, I'm thinking I could use:

1. Upserts from SQL server through MERGE statements.
2. Pass the whole XML as a parameter and use OPENXML to use as source in the MERGE statement.
3. Or, somehow generate a Table Value Parameter in C# and pass that to SQL to use on the MERGE.
4. I read on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031063/what-is-the-most-efficient-best-practise-to-upsert-5000-rows-without-merge-in) (which didnt have access to upsert/merge) that instead of trying to upsert directly from the XML, that it might be better to insert everything to a temporary table and do the merge/upsert against the temporary table?

Would this work and be considerably fast?

If anyone has had a similar scenario, can you share your thoughts/ideas about what combination of features would be best?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. I have a similar setup using XML to transfer data between an online portal and the client-server application. The rest of the setup is very similar to what you have.

The fact that your tables are not indexed is a bit of a concern, if you are comparing any fields that are not PK Fields, regardless of how you index the temp tables. It is important to have either one index with all of the fields used in the merge match clause, or an index for each of them - I find the former yields better performance. Beyond that, using an XML parameter, OpenXML and temp tables is the way to go.

The following code has not been tested, so may need a bit of debugging, but it will put you on the right track. A couple of notes: If all of the fields in the OpenXML WITH clause are attributes, then you can drop the last parameter (i.e. ", 2") and field source specifiers (i.e. "@id" for the detail table). Although the data in your description is flat, in which case you will only need one table, I do often need to import into linked records. I have included a simple master-detail relationship example in the code below, just for the sake of completeness.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_ImportFromXML (@data XML) AS
BEGIN
/*
    <root>
        <data>
            <match_field_1>1</match_field_1>
            <match_field_2>val2</match_field_2>
            <data_1>val3</data_1>
            <data_2>val4</data_2>
            <detail_records>
                <detail_data id="detailID1">
                    <detail_1>blah1<detail_1>
                    <detail_2>blah2<detail_2>
                </detail_data>
                <detail_data id="detailID2">
                    <detail_1>blah3<detail_1>
                    <detail_2>blah4<detail_2>
                </detail_data>
            </detail_records>
        </data>
        <data>
            ...
    </root>
*/
    DECLARE @iDoc INT
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @iDoc OUTPUT, @data
    SELECT * INTO #temp
    FROM OpenXML(@iDoc, '/root/data', 2) WITH (
        match_field_1 INT,
        match_field_2 VARCHAR(50),
        data_1 VARCHAR(50),
        data_2 VARCHAR(50)
    )

    SELECT * INTO #detail
    FROM OpenXML(@iDoc, '/root/data/detail_data', 2) WITH (
        match_field_1 INT '../../match_field_1',
        match_field_2 VARCHAR(50) '../../match_field_2',
        detail_id VARCHAR(50) '@id',
        detail_1 VARCHAR(50),
        detail_2 VARCHAR(50)
    )

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @iDoc

    CREATE INDEX #IX_temp ON #temp(match_field_1, match_field_2)
    CREATE INDEX #IX_detail ON #detail(match_field_1, match_field_2, detail_id)

    MERGE data_table a
        USING #temp ta
        ON ta.match_field_1 = a.match_field_1 AND ta.match_field_2 = a.match_field_2
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET data_1 = ta.data_1, data_2 = ta.data_2
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (match_field_1, match_field_2, data_1, data_2) VALUES (ta.match_field_1, ta.match_field_2, ta.data_1, ta.data_2)

    MERGE detail_table a
        USING (SELECT d.*, p._key FROM #detail d, data_table p WHERE d.match_field_1 = p.match_field_1 AND d.match_field_2 = p.match_field_2) ta
        ON a.id = ta.id AND a.parent_key = ta._key
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET detail_1 = ta.detail_1, detail2 = ta.detail_2
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (parent_key, id, detail_1, detail_2) VALUES (ta._key, ta.id, ta.detail_1, ta.detail_2)    

    DROP TABLE #temp
    DROP TABLE #detail
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter. I tried this approach, but when I passed the entire XML file as an Xml parameter to my Sproc (which does a merge), it took 7 minutes to insert 50k records, which was not acceptable. I've got it down to 1.2 seconds for 100k rows, which is pretty good, I'll post a more detailed answer later once I've perfected this thing. Thanks

Comment: Did you use an indexed staging table for the import, or try to merge directly from OpenXML? I ask the question because I've got much better performance than that, although admittedly not as good as with SqlBulkCopy. I'm looking forward to seeing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use (3). Process the data ready for upset in C#. C# is made for this kind of algorithmic work. It is both the right programming language as well as the faster programming language. T-SQL is not the right tool. You do not want to use XML with T-SQL for very high performance stuff because it burns CPU like crazy. Instead use the fast TDS protocol to send TVP or bulk data.

Then, send the data to the server using either a TVP or a bulk-insert (`SqlBulkCopy`) to a temp table. The latter technique is great for very many rows (>10k?). Bulk insert uses special TDS features. It does not use SQL batches to transfer the data. It does not get faster than this.

Then use the `MERGE` statement as you described. Use big batch sizes, potentially all rows in one batch.

Comment: Thanks @usr. I'm yet working on this thing, but got it down to about 1.5 seconds for 100k which is good enough for now. It's using SqlBulkCopy to a staging table and performing a MERGE from there.

Comment: Completely agree with this. Got an example on my blog of this exact thing, and I have yet to find a faster way to handle it. http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to bulk insert into a temp table from your C# code, then issue the merge once the data is in SQL Server. I have an example here on my blog [SQL Server Bulk Upsert](http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/)

I use this in production to insert millions of rows daily, and have yet to find a faster way to do it. Give it a try, I think you will be impressed with the performance of the solution.